# Отправлять на почту с intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

На данный момент у меня есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую я могу делать вызов.

```
this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(callButton,
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_green_sel),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel))
    {
        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
            Object tag = marker.getTag();
            if (tag != null) {
                Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + String.valueOf(tag)));
                startActivity(call);
            }
        }
    };
    this.callButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);
```

Хочу сделать аналогично для отправки email. Перешёл к офф [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email), но что то не работает(
Помогите преоборазовать корректно, в AndroidManifest всё добавил

```
<activity ...>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:type="*/*" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Вы хотите отправлять письмо сторонним почтовым клиентом или хоите написать сторонний почтовый клиент для отсылки писем?

Comment: не совсем наверное понял вас) хочу чтобы пользователь мог по нажатию на кнопку отправлять письмо на gmail (скорей всего он у него установлен)

Comment: Я что-то не пойму. Вы хотите отсылать Email, даете ссылку где говорится о том, что нужно использовать `ACTION_SENDTO`, а в коде `ACTION_DIAL` используемый для набора номера?

Comment: @UserName прочитайте внимательней описание вопроса)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для запуска интента, отображающего список приложений через которые можно отправить письмо используйте следующий [код](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9462834/3212712):

```
public static void sendEmail(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); // it's not ACTION_SEND
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:example@example.com")); // or just "mailto:" for blank
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); // this will make such that when user returns to your app, your app is displayed, instead of the email app.
    checkAndStart(context, intent, R.string.error_send_email);
}

private static void checkAndStart(Context context, Intent intent, int errorRes) {
    if (checkIntent(context, intent)) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(errorRes), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private static boolean checkIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    return activities != null && activities.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: данный метод sendEmail я могу по сути запихнуть в мой метод  onClickConfirmed? + только как корректно привязать его к тагу? или можно точно также как я использовал в примере? `marker.getTag();`

Comment: @Inkognito, я не знаю что у вас с реализацией и что в тегах и зачем они вам. Я привёл лишь код который вызовет окно выбора почтового клиента для отправки письма

Comment: спасибо конечно, но как быть с методом checkIntent?)

Comment: @Inkognito, добавил

Comment: Похоже, что код заимствован из [ответа на англоязычном Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9462834/2790048). В таких случаях всегда указывайте автора и источник.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, добавил)

Answer (score 1):

Ну если проще говоря, можно наверное было бы и так решить Вашу проблему.

```
    public  void sendEmail() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); // it's not ACTION_SEND
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject of email");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body of email");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:default@recipient.com")); // or just "mailto:" for blank
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // this will make such that when user returns to your app, your app is displayed, instead of the email app.
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Похоже, что код заимствован из [ответа на англоязычном Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9462834/2790048). В таких случаях всегда указывайте автора и источник.